# Newly installed network adapter not working

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, drivers, network-adapter

I previously had a Broadcom wireless and Bluetooth adapter installed in my laptop. This adapter worked fine on Windows 10, but always caused problems on my Linux dual-boot. After a lot of hassle attempting to get the adapter to cooperate with Linux, I decided to simply replace the adapter with an Intel Dual-Band Wireless-AC 7260 adapter, since Intel adapters are known to work easily out of the box on Linux.

I installed the adapter and booted up Windows 10. The adapter is recognised, and device manager shows that the latest drivers are installed, but I cannot turn Wifi on. The slider just slides straight back to the *off* position as soon as I switch it on. Also notably, when I click on the taskbar wifi icon it loads for about 15 seconds before anything shows with regards to wifi options. When it does load, it shows "Wifi 3" rather than just "Wifi", as it did with the old adapter.

I have manually installed drivers from the Intel Driver Update Utility program, as well as from 3rd party sources - all with no luck.

I appreciate any help in advance, thank you.

Comment: Many laptops have White/black lists of adapters in the BIOS /UEFI and they only allow those to work in the machine... The behavior you describe is typical of an adapter not in the white list. Is that adapter an OEM option in your laptop? If not, it may not work at all.

Comment: So this "slider" is intel software, there a way, to avoid that software but still have the drivers?

Comment: @acejavelin Where in UEFI do I find this list? I couldn't see anything. My laptop is an Acer Aspire V5-571P with Phoenix SecureCore Tiano UEFI. The only possibly relevant information I can see in my UEFI is an option for "Network Boot" which is disabled.

The reason I got this Intel 720 adapter is because I read in a thread somewhere that someone said it works perfectly out of the box on my.particular laptop.

Comment: @Ramhound The slider is part of Windows 10. It appears in Settings -> Network & Internet -> WiFi and is where you switch WiFi on/off.

Comment: @CornOnTheKob The "white list" isn't visible in the bios, and most manufacturers won't discuss it other than to say they only support "limited upgrades".  Best bet is to Google your model and WiFi white list, but Acer is kind of bad for this typically their list is quite restrictive. Bios-mods.com forums is a good resource for this stuff and there are request areas for white list removal.